# event called twice on SelectionListener

Tags: events

I am trying to implement an Event on a RadioButton:

```
radio_Email.addSelectionListener(
    new org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener() {
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated Event stub widgetDefaultSelected()
        }
        public void widgetSelected(org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("This is printed twice "
                    + "if i try to toggle between two radio buttons");
        }
    }
);
```

I know this is getting called twice : the first time for deselecting the first radio button and the second time for selecting the second radio button.

**But i could not figure out how to solve it....can anybody help me with this**

*Note: The radio buttons are generated dynamically so there might be n radio buttons and hence this is inside a for-loop(just in-case..some additional info)...on page load..when i select the first one, event is called once...but when I click on a second one...then the event is getting fire twice.*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

i have solved it....
modify the widgetselected method as

```
      public void widgetSelected(org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent e) {
                boolean isSelected = ((Button)e.getSource()).getSelection();
          if(isSelected){     

                               system.out.println("Now this solved the problem")

                          }           
                       }
```